# how do I change qutation/line outlay

Tags: html

Ok I am a noob

I am trying to change the line set-up of a short story. Without having to do it line by line. 
ie use find and replace all instead of Find / Relpace / Find / Find

What I have is:
"what ever text."  "what ever text."  Meg frowned. "what ever text."  "what ever text" Kat said.

What I need is:
"what ever text."
"what ever text." Meg frowned.
"what ever text."
"what ever text." Kat said.

Ty

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I could see is change

`"what ever text" Kat said`

to

`"what ever text." Kat said`

i.e. add missing fullstop.

Could you please try replacing `t"` with `t."`